# Pass a class method name as a lamba expression

Tags: c#, reflection, interface, lambda, delegates

I am writing a plugin framework for some api calls for various clients with various security requirements to collect various business-specific data.  All the plugins implement `IApiServiceEntryPoint` which looks something like this:

```
public interface IApiServiceEntryPoint : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of the API Plugin
    /// </summary>
    string Name { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the assembly in the application, sets up the routes, and enables invocation of API requests
    /// </summary>
    void Register();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the routing namespace of the plugin
    /// </summary>
    string UrlNameSpace { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the user is authorized to invoke the supplied method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="methodName"></param>
    bool IsAuthorized(string methodName);

    /// <summary>
    /// The user initiating the API call
    /// </summary>
    IPrincipal User { get; }
}
```

Please note the `IsAuthorized` method.  My intention is to allow a plugin to determine if a particular `IPrincipal` is authorized to call a specific method in the concrete class.  Using a string works, but I would rather be a bit more specific and refactorable; for example, with a lambda expression.

Currently, I can do something like this in my API controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public DateTime GetSystemTimeStamp()
    {
        if (IsAuthorized("GetSystemTimeStamp"))
        {
            return DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
        throw new AuthorizationException();
    }
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
   [HttpGet]
    public DateTime GetSystemTimeStamp()
    {
        if (IsAuthorized(me => me.GetSystemTimeStamp))
        {
            return DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
        throw new AuthorizationException();
    }
```

How would I declare that in my interface, and how would I extract the name of the method in the `IsAuthorized` method to check authorization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a lambda; you can pass the method directly as a delegate:

```
public bool IsAuthorized<T>(Func<T> method) {
    string name = method.Method.Name;
}
if (IsAuthorized(GetSystemTimeStamp))
```

You will need separate `Func<,,,T>` overloads for each arity of method you want to accept; they can all simply call a common method that takes `Delegate`.
Alternatively, you can make just one method that takes `Delegate`, then explicitly create a delegate at each callsite.

Comment: Of course, now if someone *does* pass in a lambda it'll bawk.

Comment: @Servy: It won't bawk; it will return a strange compiler-generated name.  You can check for that by looking for `CompilerGeneratedAttribute`.

Comment: And the worst that happens then is that the `IsAuthorized` check defaults to false :P

Comment: Yeah, but that's not what the OP is looking for, and since it's compiled, and not an `Expression`, there's no real good way of getting the method called inside of that anonymous method.  So it won't *work*, even though it'll compile and run without throwing exceptions. I'm not saying this isn't a good solution, because it is, I'm just explicitly stating that, if you're going to use this, you need to explicitly *not* use a lambda.  Getting it to work with lambdas would take additional effort.

Comment: Brilliant.  I was overthinking it.  Thanks!

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: Note that, as Servy points out, this will not work _at all_ with lambdas.

Comment: @SLaks Understood; the primary goal was not to have a string representing the method name so that automated refactoring would not be such a bear.  This may be considered a "workaround" but it simply accomplishes the problem I was trying to overcome.